# Orbeon Workflow-send button on specific form, not on all the forms

Tags: orbeon

How to add workflow-send button on form, that is available to that form only ?
Not for all form.
I have used this settings. but I want send button on specific form, instead of on all the form

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*" value="close clear pdf save workflow-send"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achive this by :

```
<!-- for example : CustomerDepartment Application form -->
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.CustomerDepartment.*" value="close clear workflow-send"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.AA.BB" value="submit"/>
```

Replace AA with Application Name and BB with Form Name